Forward Stability of $f(x) = x+1$
I was reading: https://www.cs.usask.ca/~spiteri/CMPT898/notes/numericalStability.pdf
Where I read that the algorithm $\tilde{f}(x)=fl(x)\bigoplus1$ for the problem $f(x)=x+1$, is stable but not backward stable. I know why this is not backward stable as there's an extra $\epsilon$ term when $x$ is small. However what about forward stability? Here's my approach:
Let $\tilde{x} = x(1+\epsilon)$
Thus,
$\dfrac{||\tilde{f}(x)-f(\tilde{x})||}{||f(\tilde{x}||} = \dfrac{|1+\epsilon_1+x(1+\epsilon_2)-x(1+\epsilon)-1|}{|1+x(1+\epsilon)|} = \dfrac{|\epsilon_1+x\epsilon_2-x\epsilon|}{|1+x(1+\epsilon)|}$
which may not be $O(\epsilon_M)$ if $x$ is very close to $-1$.
What's wrong??

It is not clear what you are doing, and your computation should yield 2.875570976809943e-11.

I am trying to compute relative forward error. Even if it is 2.87557e-11 it's still not the order of Machine epsilon.

I realised what you were saying and have fixed the exponent. Thanks for the catch @copper.hat . Still the actual issue remains

You should add the definition of $f$ that you are using so the reader has a clue.

Although it was there in the title, I have added it separately as well.

I believe I have figured this out:
if $x$ is very large (i.e. $x=\omega(1)$) then the relative forward error is close to $0$. If it's very small  (i.e. $x=o(1)$) then the 1 in the denominator of relative forward dominates and the whole fraction is $O(\epsilon_M)$. If $x$ is close to 1, (i.e. $x=\theta(1)$) then $\epsilon_3:=\dfrac{\epsilon_1}{x} = O(\epsilon_M)$ and the denominator term can be controlled as the numerator will be very small (set $\epsilon = \epsilon_2+\epsilon_3$).
Is this a correct argument?
